# Using Salesforce to Salesforce Connection to update object & Fields

Tags: integration, lookup, salesforce2salesforce

I am connecting two salesforce org using salesforce to salesforce connection - https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Salesforce_to_Salesforce

For this I have published an object from source and subscribed to the object in the target. The object and field in the object have same name in
source and target orgs. I have a lookup field in the source for the same object which I have also published along with the object.

Problem - I am unable to map the lookup field in the target org where I have subscribed for the object. It shows "none available" where I need to map the field
.Are lookup field cannot be mapped? I have tried the 
mapping with text field and I was able to map it to a correspoding field with the same name.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the same documentation , it says you cannot publish Lookup IDs.
Documentation says:

> Lookup IDs are not available for publishing. You can enable S2S for those fields by creating a formula field and then publishing the formula field

This might be the root cause.